# How to use datetime filter in django just for day and month?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-queryset

I need to filter objects of users in a viewset whose birthday is today. Here, **I will just need to check it with today's day and month irrespective of year**. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. get the date and month of day.

```
from datetime import datetime

today_day = datetime.now().day
today_month = datetime.now().month
```

2. filter objects like following.

```
today_birthdays = YourModelName.objects.filter(
    birthdate__day=today_day, birthdate__month=today_month
    )
```

here `birthdate` is your datetime field on which you want to filter.

if you want to add year also in the filter, you ll have to add `birthdate__year`. it is **double underscore** which does the magic.